# Resizing Magento watermark by percentage of the product image?

Tags: image, magento, watermark

My product images vary in width by a large range. A fixed size watermark would make it stupid on some images that is too small.

I see there's an option to specify the actual width in absolute pixels the watermark will be printed on the product images, but is there any way I can use a percentage rather than absolute values for the watermark to be used? Such as 35% the width of the original image and then resize proportionately. You get the idea.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I can get the [width of product images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286441/programmatically-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-product-image-in-magento) in Magento by:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth()
```

I can calculate watermark width on the fly:

```
$watermarkWidth = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth() * .5; // watermark width will be 50% of the original image width
```

And then calculate $watermarkHeight, the height of the watermark by proportion.

With the setWatermarkSize() method, I can now set watermark by percentage of the original image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->setWatermarkSize($watermarkWidth.'x'.$watermarkHeight);?> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to get this to work on an image gallery or just on the main image?

I used the following in media.phtml to resize the watermark:

```
   <?php
        $_originalWidth = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth();
        function iGetWatermarkSize($_originalWidth) {
    //Change the width value percentage to be what percent you want the watermark to be of the image - I want it to not display or display very small so I used .05, otherwise I would have used .9
    $_watermarkSizeWidth = .05 * $_originalWidth;
    $_watermarkSizeHeight = $_watermarkSizeWidth * 54 / 574;
    $_watermarkSize = $_watermarkSizeWidth.'x'.$_watermarkSizeHeight;
    return $_watermarkSize;
}
$_watermarkSize = iGetWatermarkSize($_originalWidth);
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->setWatermarkSize($_watermarkSize).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');


    ?>
```

I am unsure how to get it to work on a gallery image.