# Programmatically get the width and height of a product image in Magento?

Tags: image, magento

Inside Magento templating code I want to get the width and height of the original product image (uploaded by admin when creating product), so as to make according adjustments.

How can I do this? Thus far I have:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
```

Does this have any methods that would allow me to retrieve the original dimensions of the product image? Such as:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getWidth()
```

Or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found it in the docs: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image.html

Seems it's:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight()
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth()
```

Comment: How to set this getOriginalHeight() height. If suppose i am getting 891 height , now i want to remove -50 from 891 so, now its become 841. How can replace this height to original height?